# Get Integer month and year value in YYYY-MM-DD format from JS date object?

Tags: reactjs

When the user selects from the date field, it is displayed on the screen in the following format.

for example :

```
   moment(Date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') 
    
   output=> '2021-10-13'
```

How can  get month(10) and year(2021) values ​​as integer using the ('YYYY-MM-DD') format from above output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

```js
const d = new Date('2021-10-12')
const year = d.getFullYear()
const month = d.getMonth() + 1
const day = d.getDate()
console.log({year,month,day})
```